# sockets UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f

Tags: python, socket

Buenas tardes después de tengo el codigo de un cliente - servidor utilizando python y sockets para transmitir mensajes y archivos sin embargo se me presentaba un error al momento de mandar los archivos y es que llegaban de manera incompleta, pero despues de inverstigar encontre esta respuesta que me ayudo un poco: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20007319/how-to-do-a-large-text-file-transfer-in-python`

Pero no funciona mi codigo este es el codigo que ocupo:

server.py

```
import socket
import os

ip = "0.0.0.0"
puerto = 8083
data = (ip,puerto)
conexionesMaximas = 10

socketSer = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
socketSer.bind(data)
socketSer.listen(conexionesMaximas)

cliente,direccion = socketSer.accept()

longitud = os.path.getsize("Captura.PNG")

def conver_to_Bytes(no):
    result = bytearray()
    result.append(no&255)
    for i in range(3):
        no = no>>8
        result.append(no&255)
    return result

while True:
    datos = cliente.recv(1024).decode()
    print(datos)
    if datos == "exit":
        cliente.sendall("exit".encode())
        break
    elif datos == "archivo":
        cliente.send(conver_to_Bytes(longitud))
        with open("Captura.PNG",'rb') as infile:
            d = infile.read(1024)
            while d:
                cliente.send(d)
                d = infile.read(1024)
socketSer.close()
```

cliente.py

```
import socket

ipser = "192.168.8.3"
puertoSer = 8083

cliente=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
cliente.connect((ipser,puertoSer))

#recibido = open("arhivo.PNG","wb")

def bytes_to_numer(b):
    res = 0
    for i in range(4):
        res += b[i]<<(i*8)
    return res

while True:
    msg = input("> ")
    cliente.sendall(msg.encode())
    respuesta = cliente.recv(1024).decode()
    print(respuesta)
    if msg == "archvio":
        size = cliente.recv(4)
        size = bytes_to_numer(size)
        current_size = 0
        buffer = b""
        while current_size<size:
            print("recibiendo")
            data = cliente.recv(1024)
            if not data:
                break
            if len(data) + current_size>size:
                data = data[:size-current_size]
            buffer += data
            current_size+=len(data)
        with open("recibido.png","wb") as f:
            f.write(buffer)
cliente.close()
```

La intencion es la siguiente que se puedan mandar mensajes entre el cliente y el servidor y que al momento de que el servidor reciba el texto `archivo` desde el cliente entonces deberá de enviar el archivo.

Ya he intentado mucho pero no funciona espero puedan ayudarme

**TRACEBACK**

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Angel\Desktop\server.py", line 34, in <module>
    d = infile.read(1024)
  File "C:\Users\Angel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\encodings\c
p1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 57: chara
cter maps to <undefined>`

Comment: Si usas python3 debes abrir el archivo en modo binario, con `open(..., "rb")` (y en el otro extremo que lo recibe para guardarlo, también debe abrirse en modo binario, con `"wb"`, aunque eso veo que no lo tienes aún hecho)

Comment: @abulafia, podrias apoyarme con un ejemplo

Comment: @abulafia, he editado mi pregunta para que puedas ver lo que he agregado

Comment: Ok, y ¿sigue sin funcionarte tras esos añadidos? Yo acabo de poner una respuesta que más o menos hace lo mismo, la he probado, y funciona correctamente

Comment: @abulafia,despues de aplicar lo que me dijiste en tu respuesta de abajo el cliente se queda solo `>` esperando texto y si mando algo mas al servidor me lanza un error: `del tipo unicode utf-8`

Comment: Será mejor ver si lo resolvemos en el chat. A mi me está funcionando... [Entra aqui](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89522/chat-entre-abulafia-y-angel-judath-alvarez)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que te está dando se debe a que has abierto el fichero en modo texto (al ponerle la opción `"r"`) en lugar de modo binario (que sería con la opción `"rb"`).

La diferencia entre ambos modos es que cuando lees de un binario, obtienes como resultado una cadena de bytes en la que python no entra y puede tener cualquier secuencia arbitraria de bytes. En cambio cuando lees de uno de texto, aunque lo que en realidad sacas del fichero son bytes, python intenta decodificarlos como texto, usando por defecto el encoding utf-8. Si el fichero efectivamente tenía texto en ese encoding, `read()` te devolverá un string (en vez de una cadena de bytes), con el texto ya decodificado. Pero este no es el caso cuando abres un PDF, por lo que entre los bytes leidos ha aparecido uno que Python no pudo decodificar correctamente.

Este problema se resuelve simplemente abriendo el fichero con la opción `"rb"`. Aparte de eso el servidor tenía otros pequeño fallo y es que cuando recibe la cadena `"exit"` abandona el bucle cerrando el socket de escucha, pero *olvidaste cerrar también el socket de datos*. Al no hacerlo, ese socket se cerrará por si solo más tarde, pero puede tardar minutos y entretanto no te dejará volver a lanzar el servidor porque te dirá que "El socket ya está siendo usado".

Por otro lado el cliente también debería terminar cuando envía `"exit"`. Y cuando envía el comando `"archivo"` (que por cierto, tenías una errata y habías puesto `"archvio"`), aunque tienes correctamente implementada la lectura, al final el resultado lo tendrás en la variable `buffer`, con la que no haces nada. Te faltaba volcar esa variable a fichero (de nuevo abriéndolo en modo binario, pero esta vez para escribir).

Completando el cliente quedaría así:

```
import socket

ipser = "localhost"
puertoSer = 8083


cliente=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
cliente.connect((ipser,puertoSer))

def bytes_to_numer(b):
    res = 0
    for i in range(4):
        res += b[i]<<(i*8)
    return res

while True:
    msg = input("> ")
    cliente.sendall(msg.encode())

    if msg == "archivo":
        size = cliente.recv(4)
        size = bytes_to_numer(size)
        current_size = 0
        buffer = b""
        while current_size<size:
            data = cliente.recv(1024)
            if not data:
                break
            if len(data) + current_size>size:
                data = data[:size-current_size]
            buffer += data
            current_size+=len(data)

        # Faltaba esto, guardar el fichero
        with open("recibido.png", "wb") as f:
            f.write(buffer)

    # Y esto, para que el cliente también termine
    if msg == "exit":
        break
cliente.close()
```